# How to render a rgl mesh in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, rgl

Previously I was able to display a rgl mesh in Shiny with the code below, but now this throws some JavaScript errors. I read the docs and I don't see what I'm doing bad.

```r
library(shiny)
library(rgl)

options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(

    rglwidgetOutput("mesh")

)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    save <- options(rgl.inShiny = TRUE)
    on.exit(options(save))

    output$mesh <- renderRglwidget({
        try(rgl.close())
        shade3d(icosahedron3d(), color = "green")
        rglwidget()
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release version is broken, use develop version `remotes::install_github("dmurdoch/rgl")` (>= 0.109.12).

See [the issue](https://github.com/dmurdoch/rgl/issues/249)

I tested your code with develop version, no problem.